# How can I verify a Python method was called with parameters including a DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert, magicmock

I'm using MagicMock to verify that a method was called with specific arguments:

```
ClassToMock.method_to_mock = MagicMock(name='method_to_mock')
ClassToMock.method_that_creates_data_frame_and_passes_to_mocking_method()
ClassToMock.method_to_mock.assert_called_with('test_parameter_value', self.get_test_data_frame())
```

Where `self.get_test_data_frame()` is a pre-defined DataFrame that is the expected result of the call.

When I print out the DataFrame passed to the mocking method and the the test DataFrame I can see that they look equal when printed:

[image]

but the test output does not think they are equal:

> File "C:\python3.6\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 812, in
> assert_called_with
> if expected != actual:   File "C:\python3.6\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 2055, in **eq**
> return (other_args, other_kwargs) == (self_args, self_kwargs)   File "C:\python3.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line
> 1330, in **nonzero**
> f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. " ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

From reading other issues I think it is because the MagicMock tries to call == but Pandas require .equals() to check for equality. Does anyone know of an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some more digging and came across [call_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) which captures all of the parameters that were passed.

Even more useful for me was [call_args_list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) as my method can be called multiple times.

The `call_args_list` provides a lit of all the calls that were made in the form of tuples.

In my example I captured the `call_args_list` with the following:

```
call_list = ClassToMock.method_to_mock.call_args_list
```

I then unpacked the tuples to get the DataFrame and was able to check equality with the .equals() method.